# how do I do an if doesn't include statement with an array without using const?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and I wasn't able to make an `if doesn't include` statement without changing my array to `const` which ruins it. I was wondering if there is an option without `const`

I also tried

```
if (array.includes("tom")!=true)
```

and also tried

```
if (array.includes("tom")==true)
```

Comment: Include your full (or a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) code. What error exactly you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if (!array.includes("tom")) { ... }
```

I'm not sure why your `array` needs to be `const`, it should not affect the behavior of the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method. But since the method returns a boolean, to get the logical inverse of a boolean value, you can use the [`!` (NOT)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) operator in front of the value. Thus, `!array.includes("tom")` is equivalent to saying "does the array NOT include the string 'tom'".

However, your first condition `array.includes("tom")!=true` is technically equivalent as well, but you should prefer to write `!array.includes("tom")` becauses it tends to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an exclamation point (`!`) before `array` to invert the expression `array.includes("tom")`. You can read it as "if array does not include 'tom'"

```js
let array1 = ["john", "joe", "amy"];
let array2 = ["rudy", "tom", "jeffrey"];

if (!array1.includes("tom")) {
  console.log("array1 does not include 'tom'");
} else {
  console.log("array1 includes 'tom'");
}

if (!array2.includes("tom")) {
  console.log("array2 does not include 'tom'");
} else {
  console.log("array2 includes 'tom'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.includes() method is used to determine whether the assigned array contains the value mentioned or not and will return a boolean value as True or False as the returned output.

For Example: arr.includes("tom") : arr is an array and if that array contains the value "tom" it will return true or else will return false.

So, in your code you can write the if conditions in various manner:

1. `if (array.includes("tom") !== true)` or `if (array.includes("tom") === true)` , making sure it is a strict equality.
2. `if (!array.includes("tom"))` or `if (array.includes("tom"))` , as we know that the return form the includes() method is a true or false boolean value.